# Raspberry Pi: able to access through own network but not internet

Tags: configuration, dns, raspberry-pi

I'm currently learning how to set up a web server using Raspberry Pi as a diy project.

I followed instructions on guides around the Internet (maybe thats why it screwed up because I combined instructions from different guides). Port forwarding and uploading of files all done but I am only able to access the website through my network (lan and wireless) but not able to access it threw the Internet. Any solutions?

Comment: Please specify at least those portions of the tutorials which you think might have caused the issue. Otherwise the question seems too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all, before you check anything else, are you forwarding the correct ports to the correct I.P. address?
- After you check that, are there any firewalls in place on you
  Raspberry Pi that might close down all connections form outside the
  network.
- Another thing you might want to check is if your ISP (Internet
  Service Provider) allows portforwarding on the ports you wish to use
  (typically 80 and or 443). If that is not the case, you may want to
  try to forward to another port and just connect from outside the
  network through that port (you add `:portnumber` after the URL or
  I.P. address in the browser).
- If all else fails, install a web server (apache) with `sudo apt-get
  install apache2 -y`on a vanilla raspbian image and then follow [this
  tutorial](http://raspberrywebserver.com/serveradmin/get-your-raspberry-pi-web-site-on-line.html) that explains how toset up port forwarding (in greater
  detail than what I have just done).

If you follow these steps you should have a web server up, running, and accessible from outside of your network.